# Use an associated model's attribute in a POST operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have two models that are associated with each other in a has_one and belongs_to relatiionship. When I POST a new :foo object (using the "create" method in the :foo controller), I would like to also be able to do an operation using the associated attributes  of the :bar model and then return the the user the results of a particular operation without forcing the user to do another POST operation. Is this possible, or do I need to first POST and save the :foo model in order to obtain the attributes of the :bar model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method one one of models, for more information please refer to API documentation.